# Call Databricks notebook in a specific branch from Data Factory?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, databricks-repos

I'm using the new Databricks Repos functionality and in Data Factory UI for the notebook activity you can browse the Databricks workspace and select Repos > username > project > folder > notebook.

Is it possible to call a Databricks notebook in a specific branch from Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (now) call only the notebook that belongs to checkout of specific version - if you have checkout in another version, then it's impossible to call another version. Like, if you have checkout at `master` but want to call code from `release` branch, then you need to have checkout of that branch.

But you may have multiple Repos associated with the same Git repository, but with different versions checked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a specific branch in Databricks from Data Factory. Our solution is creating multiple folders in Databricks with the same repository but a different branch.

With dynamic content in Data Factory we can load the paths from SQL Server and call them. (or hardcode it with if/else and vars in DF).

[image: different branches in databricks]